# Why does typescript transpile dead code for decorators?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, transpiler

in my transpiled code, I see this:

```
var __decorate = undefined && undefined.__decorate || function (decorators, target, key, desc) { // ...
```

`undefined && undefined.__decorate` should always be falsey.
and the the function then MUST be the value of `__decorate`. My hunch is that `undefined` *was* some variable, and got swapped out with a value at build-time.

My question: why wouldn't TS remove the forever-falsey expression?

#### UPDATE:

thanks to [@Matt McCutchen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4468617/matt-mccutchen),

Typescript itself has a `this` referenced, mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/transformers/ts.ts#L3650-L3654).

So, maybe babel is doing something with that?

Comment: Are you using another build tool in combination with TypeScript?  You can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/transformers/ts.ts#L3650-L3654) that TypeScript always outputs the code with `this`.  The other tool may have replaced `this` with `undefined` if it wanted to prevent access to the global object.

Comment: ah, interesting. cool.
yeah, babel runs over the code next, so there must be something weird  happening there.